# Solve matrix equation - verification

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I wanted to solve the following matrix equation ($\mathcal{S}$) : $(X + \mathrm{I}_{2})^{2} = \mathrm{I}_{2}$ where $X \in \mathcal{M}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$. Since every matrix of $\mathcal{M}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ is triangularizable, I can write :

$$ X = P \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_{1} & t \\ 0 & \lambda_{2} \end{bmatrix} P^{-1} $$

where $P \in \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$. I have found the following solutions :

$$ \left\{ P\begin{bmatrix} 0 & t \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}P^{-1} \quad \mathrm{or} \quad P\begin{bmatrix} -2 & t \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}P^{-1} \quad \mathrm{or} \quad P\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}P^{-1}, \, P \in \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{C}), \, t \in \mathbb{C} \right\} \cup \left\{ 0 \right\}.$$

I would like to prove that this set of solutions is the union of $3$ different equivalence classes. Is it OK to say it is the reunion of : the equivalence class of $0$, $\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} -2 & t \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that works.  Note that any solution to this equation is actually diagonalizable, so the $t$ is unnecessary.

Comment: You're right, thanks !